# Problem : randomly generate data from a table with a factory

Tags: laravel, factory

I want take a **random id** already existing from my `garage` table, so i have a problem.

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Car;
use App\Models\Garage;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class CarFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Car::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->name(),
            'release_year' => $this->faker->year(),
            'garage_id' => Garage::inRandomOrder('id')->first('id'),
            'created_at' => now()
        ];
    }
}
```

The Problème is :

> PHP Deprecated:  Since fakerphp/faker 1.14: Accessing
> property "name" is deprecated, use "name()" instead. in
> /data/www-local/web/lara_sites/swan-formation-laravel/vendor/symfony/deprecation-contracts/function.php
> on line 25 PHP Deprecated:  Since fakerphp/faker
> 1.14: Accessing property "year" is deprecated, use "year()" instead. in
> /data/www-local/web/lara_sites/swan-formation-laravel/vendor/symfony/deprecation-contracts/function.php
> on line 25 Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message
> 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
> 'garage_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `cars` (`name`,
> `release_year`, `garage_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) values (Alf
> Bayer, 1994, ?, 2021-10-05 16:21:19, 2021-10-05 16:21:19))'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [inRandomOrder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#random-ordering) method may be used to sort the query results randomly.
it has no argument, you can use it like:

```
 'garage_id' => Garage::inRandomOrder()->first()->id,
```

you should make sure of that your garages table is not empty.

Comment: I made the change but I still have the same problem, I also checked that my garage table was not empty

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
'garage_id' => $this->faker->randomElement(Garage::query()->get('id')),
```

Comment: always the same problem

Comment: Place check to see if there is any data on your garage table ?